# SQL parse text in field

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to parse a string using SQL but am too and still learning. I have text in a control or field 685 that is variable, but always the same format.

**field 685 input**

```
arr[hg19] 2q33.3q34(200,900,700-209,000,000)x2 xxx
```

**Desired output**

```
2:200900700-209000000
```

Basically, the # after the [hg19] but before the q (could also be a p) and the #'s in the () without the commas.

My attempt (though I'm not confident in it at all)

Thank you very much :).

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('[685]', ' ', '.'), 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this in SQL instead of in PHP, C# or whatever language you are using?

Comment: The application is written in SQL, so I need a button to parse in SQL.  I agree shell scripting languages would be ideal.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  The code should explain itself: solve using your knowledge of the input along with repeated use of CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING. You could combine this into one very long line of unreadable code, or use as is:

```
declare @s as varchar(100)
set @s = 'arr[hg19] 23q33.3q34(200,900,700-209,000,000)x2 xxx'
declare @ixBrace as integer;  set @ixBrace = CHARINDEX(']',@s,0)
declare @ixP as integer;      set @ixP = CHARINDEX('p',@s,@ixBRace)
declare @ixQ as integer;      set @ixQ = CHARINDEX('q',@s,@ixBRace)
declare @ixPQ as integer;     set @ixPQ = case when @ixP = 0 then @ixQ when @ixQ = 0 then @ixP when @ixP < @ixQ then @ixP else @ixQ end
declare @ixLParen as integer; set @ixLParen = CHARINDEX('(',@s,@ixPQ)
declare @ixMinus as integer;  set @ixMinus = CHARINDEX('-',@s,@ixLParen)
declare @ixRParen as integer; set @ixRParen = CHARINDEX(')',@s,@ixMinus)
select SUBSTRING(@s,@ixBrace+1,@ixPQ-@ixBrace-1) + ':' +
       REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@s,@ixLParen+1,@ixMinus-@ixLParen-1),',','') + '-' +
       REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@s,@ixMinus+1,@ixRParen-@ixMinus-1),',','')
```

Comment: could `set @s = '[685]'`.... [685] is the control where the input will be pasted into (since it will change everytime).  Thank you :).

Comment: Yes, you should be able to set `@s` to whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the '2:' comes from so I guessed it came from the 'x2'

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100) = 'arr[hg19] 2q33.3q34(200,900,700-209,000,000)x2 xxx'

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@input,PATINDEX('%x[0-9]%',@input) + 1,CHARINDEX(' xxx',@input) - PATINDEX('%x[0-9]%',@input) - 1) + ':' +
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@input,CHARINDEX('(',@input) + 1,CHARINDEX(')',@input) - CHARINDEX('(',@input) - 1),',','')
```